# How many ways can I connect labeled trees into a tree.

Tags: combinatorics, trees

Suppose I have the labeled trees $T_{1}, \ldots, T_{n}$ with $b_{1}, \ldots, b_{n}$ vertices respectively. I would like to know how many ways I can compose a tree from these trees by using all trees? In [this problem editorial](http://blog.hackerrank.com/bead-ornaments-challenge/) they claim that there are $\prod_{i=1}^{n}{b_{i}} \cdot \left( \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{b_{i}} \right)^{n - 2}$ such compositions. I don't know how to prove this and there is no proof linked on the editorial either. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is listed in [Lovasz's problem book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Combinatorial-Problems-Exercises-Chelsea-Publishing/dp/0821842625/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1435680335&sr=8-1&keywords=lovasz). This is problem 4 in chapter 4. The original solution is attributed to J. W. Moon, but I haven't managed to find the article describing this. The proof is fairly complicated so it's not a surprise that it's omitted from the editorial.

EDIT: Seems like Igor Pak shared the [original book](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/hidden/papers/Moon-counting_labelled_trees.pdf) as well, although the book by Lovasz is more accessible and the proof is complicated but well presented.